# Magento 1 catalog_product_flat_1 corrupt

Tags: magento-1.9, database, flat-catalog

We have disabled the option to use catalog flat product.

Not we have a corrupt DB message:

```
magento.catalog_product_flat_1
Error    : Incorrect information in file: './magento/catalog_product_flat_1.frm'
error    : Corrupt
```

How can we solve this?

Can we for example safely remove the table: **catalog_product_flat_1**?

Comment: Try reindexing from index management or using shell and  recompile Magento using shell. Magento shell file is mage which you can find in root directory of your Magento

Comment: Delete all the tables catalog_product_flat_* and then try reindexing.

Comment: @KumarM Thanks a lot! How can we recompile Magento using shell? This is a Magento 2 feature, right?

Comment: No Magento 1 has shell also, check a folder named "shell" in root folder of Magento

Comment: @SukumarGorai Sadly we can not delete the table. We get the error: `#1347 - 'magento.catalog_product_flat_1' is not VIEW`

Answer (score 1):

To run index and compilation use this using shell:

> Goto your Magento root directory in shell/terminal

Then

```
php shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

To compile

```
php shell/compiler.php compile
```

Comment: Thanks, it sadly did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If your database is corrupted then Magento 1 has one tool for database repair.

Here is the link for [Database Repair Tool](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/database-repair-tool.html)

You need to clone the corrupted database and then perform the tasks according to the document.

Please take a backup of database and files before doing anything to live server.

Comment: Many thanks, but we face some issues with the script. See: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238990/magento-database-repair-tool-error-mysql-fetch-row