# Magento Database Repair Tool error mysql_fetch_row

Tags: magento-1.9, database

We want to run the **Magento 1 Database Repair Tool**, but we are getting some errors.

What am I missing?

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /magento-db-repair-tool-1.2.php on line 386

Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /magento-db-repair-tool-1.2.php on line 399

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /magento-db-repair-tool-1.2.php on line 1664
```